# How to render view after ajax in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm trying to make a search by fiield using ajax request. This is my **Controller:**

```
public function actionUpdateAjax()
    {

        $model=new DeliveyInfo();
        $rows =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('fio, date, status')
            ->from('delivey_info')
            ->where('code=:code', array(':code'=>$_POST['word']))
            ->queryRow();

        $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent',array(
            'model'=>$model,'rows'=>$rows,
        ));
     }
```

This is my view where I use ajax:

```
<?php
/* @var $this DeliveyInfoController */
/* @var $model DeliveyInfo */
?>
<div id="info"></div>
<p>
    <input id="word" type="text" name="word" />
    <input id="YII_CSRF_TOKEN" type="hidden" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN" />
    <?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
</p>
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('find', "

$('.search-button').click(function(){
    var url = '/deliveyInfo/UpdateAjax';
    var word = $('#word').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            word: word,
            'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' : '" . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . "'
        },

     })
    });
");

?>
```

I have answer in console but why _ajaxContent view doesn't show after renderPartial?

Comment: where is the script to show the ajax content? you didnt set in div or anything after ajax success.

Comment: I need to show $rows in my view

Comment: I don't understand what i have to write on success

Comment: i mean where to show in your view page.

Comment: in action UpdateAjax() I render view _ajaxContent where I want to show $rows: <?php var_dump($rows); ?>

Comment: I mean you want to load the ajax response in your gridview. You are not updating your grid as per the script you give. Better redo your search form creation from your gii.

Comment: First i used advansed search from gii, but there is grid show all records and after search show my record. I don't understand how to hide grid first and just show it after click on search. if I use display: none than it didn't show after click on search

Comment: You can hide the the grid section based on the $_POST set or not. Use if condition with $_POST to do it.